# How to locate elements on a javascript form using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a page that renders a login form. Using Firefox's firebug I have identified the username id = txtUsername and the password text box is txtPassword. Everything is fine in Firefox. BUT moving over to IE Explorer browser, am getting error and cant locate the elements.

On inspecting the page, I found the form is being rendered by a JavaScript function. Below is the html:

```
form name="frmLogin" id="frmLogin" onsubmit="return $('#frmLogon').valid();" action="default.aspx" method="post" jQuery172043="1" novalidate="novalidate"
```

How can I locate the page elements using selenium webdriver.

This is the code I have written.

```
            /* setup for IE. Remove if not needed  */
            File file = new File("C:/SeleniumJavaLibrary/selenium-2.28.0/IEDriverServer.exe");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());

            DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
            caps.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
            WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(28,TimeUnit.SECONDS );
            /*setup for IE*/

            driver.get("http://website.com");
            WebElement element = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return $('#frmLogin').valid();");

            element.findElement(By.name("txtUsername")).sendKeys("user");
            element.findElement(By.name("txtPassword")).sendKeys("password");
```

Comment: That only works in Firefox

Comment: Try Java Script Executor class to perform the action.

Comment: What version of Selenium? What version of IE? What version of the IEDriver? What OS? Is the element visible when the page loads? Have you tried explicit waits? Have you tried other locators?

Comment: I have added my codes above. If that will help. Thanks

Comment: This is incorrect: `return $('#frmLogin').valid()`. You want just: `return $('#frmLogin');`

Comment: I still go the the following error: INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```
WebDriverWait waiting = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15, 100);

WebElement element = waiting.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("frmLogin")));
```

This will create a WebDriverWait object that will wait up to 15 seconds, checking to see if the expected condition is valid every 100 milliseconds.  This object is then used to wait until the frmLogin element is visible on the page, and then returns you a WebElement that can be used later on in your test (if required).